# I thought 2d Arrays get converted to 1d arrays by the compiler, why is it faster even when taking cache misses into consideration?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, optimization

I read the top posts here #performance and #optimization and there were a lot of posts about 2d array performance, they were mostly for c and c++ and said the best practice would be to switch x and y iteration to limit cache-misses.

I tried the same out in C# and even tried a 1d approach to a 2d array and it was considerably faster. Why is my 1d version a lot faster than the (optimal?) 2d one? Am I generating even fewer cache misses?

Setup:

```
int[,] testArr = new int[testSize, testSize];
int[] testArr1Dim = new int[testSize * testSize];
Random r = new Random();
for (int x = 0; x < testSize; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < testSize; y++)
    {
        int tmp = r.Next();
        testArr[x, y] = tmp;
        testArr1Dim[(y + x * testSize)] = tmp;
    }
 }
```

Slow 2d Array iteration:

```
 for (int y = 0; y < testSize; y++)
 {
                for (int x = 0; x < testSize; x++)
                {
                    counter += testArr[x, y]+2;
                }
  }
```

Fast 2d Array iteration: a bit more than twice the speed of slow 2d array

```
 for (int x = 0; x < testSize; x++)
 {
                for (int y = 0; y < testSize; y++)
                {
                    counter += testArr[x, y]+2;
                }
  }
```

1d Array iteration: a bit more than twice the speed of fast 2d array

```
for (int x = 0; x < testSize; x++)
{
                for (int y = 0; y < testSize; y++)
                {
                    counter += testArr1Dim[(y + x * testSize)]+2;
                }
}
```

HansPassant suggester a jagged array: ~10% slower than 1d Array

```
for (int x = 0; x < testSize; x++)
{
                for (int y = 0; y < testSize; y++)
                {
                    counter += jaggedArr[x][y]+2;
                }
}
```

HansPassant suggested hoisting the jagged array: This is faster than the 1d approach

```
for (int x = 0; x < testSize; x++)
{
                var col = jaggedArr[x];
                for (int y = 0; y < testSize; y++)
                {
                    counter +=col[y]+2;
                }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear where the expectation in your question title comes from. In the CLR, there are vectors and arrays - `int[]` will be a vector, and `int[,]` will be an array. Vectors are far more heavily optimized. (They always have 0 lower bounds, and a rank of 1.)

Comment: This is well documented on the web. The JIT does not optimize multi-dimensional arrays very much. A Google search will turn up a lot more than an answer can provide here (which will only repeat other answers).

Comment: First version is slow because it doesn't use the processor caches effectively.  Fixed in the second version, you now address memory in storage order.  Third version is faster because you avoid a call into a CLR helper method that indexes a multi-dimensional array and only pay for *one* index out-of-bound check instead of two.  Always favor a jagged array for speedy multi-dimensional arrays, you want int[][].

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the info. I just tried it out. The jagged array does perform considerably better, onedimensional still outperforms by about 10%

Comment: Maybe you didn't hoist the outer array access out of the loop.  That would make the jagged array access completely equivalent to a vector array access.  But in general perf differences of < 15% are not statistically meaningful, a mis-aligned branch target is already enough to produce a measurable difference.

Comment: @HansPassant wow, hoisting made it a bit faster than the 1d approach. Do you want to post an answer? I added your suggestions to my OP

Comment: I think you got what you need to complete the Q+A you started by yourself.  Just write your own post and mark it as the answer to close your question, ought to be useful to other programmers.

Comment: @HansPassant Oh one last thing: is the memory footprint difference (considering a fixed dimension size) for the 1d and jagged array approach negligible?

Comment: It will be slightly bigger because the outer array stores references to the inner arrays.  Your tests ought to have proven that the difference is negligible :)

Comment: Your 2d array accesses incur two bounds checks. Your 1d array accesses incur a single bounds check. Depending on your array dimensions, it may be possible to create x and y values that wouldn't be valid in a 2d array (e.g. using a negative index for one or other of them) but your calculated single index is within the bounds of the array.